# How to prevent right-click Google search from opening side panel in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, search, user-interface

In Chrome 115 (currently Beta channel) the "new" right-click Google search ignores the flag (chrome://flags/#search-web-in-side-panel) which I have seen documented as supposedly being there to toggle opening search results in a side panel.

How else can I fix this annoying browser behavior?

And before you ask, yes, I have relaunched the browser, rebooted, and all the rest, after setting this.

[showing #search-web-in-side-panel flag is disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZcbR.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.